# why float & inline-block cause different vertical type?

Tags: html, css

[Here is my case code.](https://jsfiddle.net/g0cssgzn/)

I create a `div` which contain element `i`. The `i` has `width` and `height` attribute and I achieve it with different way. So ,I encounter the line-height issue. I know a little about `float` vs `inline-block`. But, What cause out the line-height in my case?

Comment: float breaks a line or comes against another floatting element  to the top . Inline-block sets on line-height and in the flow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`inline-block` is treated as an inline element (like text). If it is taller than other inline elements in the same line, it forces the line-height to be taller. You can use `vertical-align:top|middle|bottom;` to change the alignment of the inline-block element (more options for `vertical-align` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

A floated element is just pushed to one side or the other, and the text flows around it.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance.